# Get Random Result and Limit Output from Hashie::Mash Loop Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, json, api, instagram

I'm using the Instagram API to get a user's feed of photos. The output looks something like this:

```
 [#<Hashie::Mash attribution=nil caption=nil comments=#<Hashie::Mash count=0 data=[]> created_time="1330231732" filter="Sutro" id="1403234234201396589_3002382" images=#<Hashie::Mash low_resolution=#<Hashie::Mash height=306 url="http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/8fd08dfsdfsdf111e180d51231380fcd7e_6.jpg" width=306>
```

I can happily loop through and display all the images or a specific one using this:

```
  Instagram.user_recent_media(@client.user.id).each do |test|
    %img{:src=>"#{test.images.low_resolution.url}"}
```

How is it possible to get a random result out and limit to only one image displayed? I've tried using limit(x) but that throws an error. Am just wanting to display one image at random, not the whole stream.

Comment: WOOOPW! Thanks, didn't even know about that. Cheers. S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
media = Instagram.user_recent_media(@client.user.id)
puts media.class
```

gives:

```
Array
```

knowing it's an array you can then easily get a random element using the `sample` method:

```
random = media.sample
puts "#{random.images.low_resolution.url}"
```

notice that the `sample` method is named `choice` in Ruby 1.8.7.